# python local variable bizarre behavior

Tags: python, namespaces, garbage-collection

Could python experts explain the following output to me?

```
def modify_dict(exclude_params):
    exclude_params["domain_url"] = set()

def g(exclude_params={}):
    print id(exclude_params)
    print exclude_params
    modify_dict(exclude_params)
    print exclude_params
    return None

>>> g()
23191104
{}
{'domain_url': set([])}
>>> g()
23191104
{'domain_url': set([])}
{'domain_url': set([])}
>>>
```

I passed no argument to `g` in either call, so local variable `exclude_params` should be initialized to `{}`.
But on the second call, it wasn't.

Even stranger, the addresses of the local variables are the same in the two separate calls. So the old local variable is reused ??!!!

Comment: Sigh.  Yet another failure to search for "mutable objects as default values".

Comment: I searched the wrong keywords, I thought this has something to do with namespace and garbage collection.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It doesn't work that way. When the function is defined, the default argument is set once and for all and shared between all function calls. Proper idiom for this is:

```
def foo(some_dict=None):
  if some_dict is None:
    some_dict = {}
```

That's because:

```
def foo(arg={})
```

is an instruction just like any other, which means, that `{}` is instantized at this place exactly and done only once.

Answer (score 0):

gruszczy is correct. This is the main thing to "bite" new people in Python, you'll find loads of questions about this here on SO.

To explain some more, the *definition* of a function is executed when the function is *defined*, not when it is called. So the parameter `some_dict` will also be set to a dictionary when the function is defined, not when it is called, as that is a part of the function definition.

At least that's how I find it helpful to think about it.